# What is best way to reset values of a dynamic object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a dynamic object :

```
  input: {
   key1: 'text1',
   key2: 10000,
   key3: 3456,
   key4: 'text2',
   key5: ['v1','v2','v3'] .....
}
```

I would like to reset it to

```
output
{
       key1: '',
       key2: 0,
       key3: 0,
       key4: '',
       key5: []
.......
}
```

I didn't find any direct method to do this, I know to do this with looping. I was wondering if we have best method/best practices to acheive output.

Comment: Can we achieve on dynamic object.?

Answer (score 1):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with an object of the wanted values.

This method does not replace unknown properties. In this case, you need a new object, or you need to delete all propeties in advance.

```js
const
    values = { key1: '', key2: 0, key3: 0, key4: '', key5: [] },
    input = { key1: 'text1', key2: 10000, key3: 3456, key4: 'text2', key5: ['v1','v2','v3'] };

Object.assign(input, values);

console.log(input);
```

A dynamic object with deleting own enumerable properties.

```js
const
    values = { key1: '', key2: 0, key3: 0, key4: '', key5: [] },
    input = { foo: '42', bar: '101', key1: 'text1', key2: 10000, key3: 3456, key4: 'text2', key5: ['v1','v2','v3'] };


Object.keys(input).forEach(Reflect.deleteProperty.bind(null, input));
Object.assign(input, values);

console.log(input);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can we achieve it in dynamic object.

Answer (score 1):

You can define all the default values in an object, and use the `spread` operator

```js
let input = {key1:'text1', key2:10000, key3:3456, key4:'text2', key5:['v1','v2','v3']}

const defaultValues = {key1:'', key2:0, key3:0, key4:'', key5:[]}

input = {
  ...defaultValues
}

console.log(input)
```

You can loop through all the elements in the object and based on the type of the property we can reset it to default value. Below is the example.

```js
let input = {key1:'text1', key2:10000, key3:3456, key4:'text2', key5:['v1','v2','v3']}

const resetData = (data) => {
  let keys = Object.keys(data);
  let dataCopy = {};
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if(Array.isArray(data[key])) {
      dataCopy[key] = []
    } else if(typeof data[key] === "object") {
      dataCopy[key] = {}
    } else if(typeof data[key] === "string") {
      dataCopy[key] = ""
    } else {
      dataCopy[key] = 0
    }
  })

  return dataCopy;
}

console.log(resetData(input));

input = {key6: {abc: "123"}, key7: "dummy", key8: [1, 2, 3] }

console.log(resetData(input));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can we achieve it in dynamic object.